# OnActionExecuted: no suitable method found to override

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am getting an `error`

> OnActionExecuted: no suitable method found to override

```
public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
         filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
        }
```

I want to execute this code after method execution.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the method signatures :

```
protected virtual void OnActionExecuted (System.Web.Mvc.ActionExecutedContext filterContext);
```

You have incorrect type of parameter in your override. It expects a parameter of type `ActionExecutedContext` not `ActionExecutingContext`. See [OnActionExecuted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controller.onactionexecuted?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2)

It should be:

```
public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext) 
{
   // code goes here
}
```